# AVAudioPlayer change sound URL on the fly

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

In my init method I initialise the sound_a.wav like this.

```
    AVAudioPlayer *snd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    URLForResource:@"sound_a" withExtension:@"wav"] error: nil];
```

Depending on the scenario I need to play a different sound (let's assume that sound is sound_b).

What code do I need to change this on the fly?

Comment: Check my answer.  `AVQueuePlayer` can help you

Answer (score 5):

First if `AVAudioPlayer` still playing, stop it:

```
if([snd isPlaying]){
    [snd stop];
}
```

Then, recreate new `AVAudioPlayer` with new URL. **My first suggestion to reinit the player will not work**. You have to create a new instance.

```
snd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"sound_b" withExtension:@"wav"] error: nil];
[snd play];
```

Better solution is to use [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/index.html) for multiple sounds:

```
AVPlayerItem *item1 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sound_a"]];
AVPlayerItem *item2 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sound_b"]];
AVQueuePlayer *player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:@[item1, item2]];

[player play];

[...]

[player advanceToNextItem];
```

Comment: Looks that URL is readonly @property(readonly) NSURL *url; /* returns nil if object was not created with a URL */

Comment: what about `[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    URLForResource:@"sound_b" withExtension:@"wav"]` ?

Comment: this is what I am asking actually, can I update the URL or not?

Comment: You can't update the URL, only instantiate a new player with another URL. Initialization takes a time, so you can't use this solution to play new sound on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "Scenario" means here. But, you could play random sounds by creating an array with a list of sounds and generating a random index each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of AVAudioPlayer for all sounds you want to play and use [prepareToPlay](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/prepareToPlay) to preload their buffers. Then when you need to play another sound just stop previous player with `stop` method and play another player (for next sound) with `playAtTime:`.

Comment: why I need playAtTime? play sound be fine, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on your needs. I suggest you to use `playWithTime:` because this player can be played previously and will have a different `currentTime`. In this situation call `[player playWithTime:0]` to play from the start.

Comment: [player playWithTime:0] is the same with [player play], correct?

Comment: `[player play]` plays from `player.currentTime`, `[player playAtTime:0]` plays from start